# Lost desktop menu terminal

Tags: startup

I run lubuntu 14.04. I was updating libreoffice and when I rebooted the familiar mushroom desktop image appeared and I logged in as usual. Then nothing. No desktop (just mushroom) no menu, can't get a terminal up with  ctrl alt T.

I can log into Ubuntu but that always crashes (hence using lubuntu - it's an old pc) and I can log in as guest where everything is normal.

Any suggestions how I get back to normal?

Ps I'm not a complete novice but no expert either!

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you invoke the grub menu by holding down the shift key during power up? If so choose another kernel to test, or choose memory test, or choose recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Login to lubuntu

Press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

Sometimes  <kbd>F2</kbd>

Virtual terminal opens. Type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

Now you are all good to go

Comment: Guys thanks so much. Yesterday I installed lubuntu 16.04 over the top and everything working fine again. I couldn't get a terminal up or anything and of course although I could log in as guest where things ran normally Ian couldn't root. So thanks for you suggestions and help very much.  All sorted.

Comment: Did you try to open the virtual terminal?